# Saber si es una imagen o link PHP

Tags: php

Estoy escribiendo un código que consiste en leer archivos de una carpeta en la que hay imágenes y links, y necesito diferenciar entre imagen y link, pero me he quedado muy muy pillado. El código es este por si me podéis ayudar:

```
//Leer archivos de la carpeta
            $filehandle = opendir($ruta); // Abrir archivos de la carpeta
            //Bucle para seleccionar filas y columnas
            for($i=0; $i<$numFilas; $i++){
                $Visualizacion .= "<tr>";
                for($w=0; $w<$numColumnas; $w++){
                    $Visualizacion .= "<td>";
                        while($file = readdir($filehandle)){
                            if($file != "." && $file != ".."){
                                $tamanyo = GetImageSize($ruta . $file);
                                $rutaFile = "$ruta$file";

                                $Visualizacion .= "<td><a TARGET = '_top' href = '$ruta$file'><img src='$ruta$file' $tamanyo[3]></a></td>";

                                $patron = "/I_(.*)_IH_(.*)_HP_(.*)_PN_(.*)_N\./";
                                $result = preg_match($patron, $file, $resultados);

                                $nombreCompleto = $resultados[0];
                                $vecesMostrar = $resultados[1];
                                $horariosProhibidos = $resultados[2];
                                $periodo = $resultados[3];
                                $nombre = $resultados[4];
                                $rutaCompleta = "$ruta$file";

                                //Llamo a la función que se encarga de agregar los registros
                                agregarImpresiones($nombre,$ruta, $vecesMostrar, $horariosProhibidos, $periodo);
                                impresionesTotales($nombre, $ruta, $periodo, $vecesMostrar, $rutaCompleta);
                                break;
                            }//end if
                        }//end while
                    $Visualizacion .= "</td>";                          
                }//end for
                $Visualizacion .= "</tr>";
            }//end for

            closedir($filehandle); // Fin lectura archivos
```

Con el filehandle entiendo que lee todos los archivos, pero cómo los diferencia?? Muchas gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: Yo tengo una pregunta... qué es exactamente un "link" como fichero en el disco duro?
Respecto a lo que preguntas... donde guardas $tamanyo, si es una imagen te dará un tamaño real, si GetImageSize no recibe una imagen, dará FALSE, por tanto... es link.

Comment: Por otro lado, cuando pones  $result = preg_match($patron, $file, $resultados);.... $resultados qué tiene, de dónde viene esa variable?

Comment: @VeraCanet Hola buenas! A link me refiero a un archivo .txt con un enlace dentro. Osea, si pongo if( $tamanyo = FALSE){ echo " no es una imagen"; } por ejempo, me detectaría qué es una imagen y qué no?

Comment: @VeraCanet La variable $resultados no tiene nada que ver, es donde guardo los patrones del nombre del archivo, pero ya te digo que eso no es importante jaja

Comment: **link**... se puede filosofar sobre esa palabra. ¿Qué es un link? ¿Te refieres a una url del navegador con un *anchor tag*? ¿Son admitidos links usando `localhost`? ¿Quieres saber simplemente si es una url bien formada o validar también que es una url que **funcione**? ¿Son admitidos links del tipo `ftp:, ssh:, mailto...`? Sobre **links** se puede escribir un libro, hay muchos tipos de links.

Comment: @A.Cedano A link me refiero a una URL del navegador, funcione o no, o del tipo que sea. Más que nada, diferenciar entre un archivo de imagen y un archivo de texto

Comment: Pero es que también una imagen puede ser un link, o estar dentro de un link... creo que le falta claridad a tu pregunta. Quizá arrojaría un poco de luz que pusieras algunos ejemplos de la salida que obtienes en tu código. Si lo que quieres es saber el tipo de archivo, una cosa que puedes hacer es capturar la última parte y compararla en base a su extensión.

Comment: no entiendo tu comentario @A.Cedano. Una imagen "como archivo" puede ser un link? Csc99 pregunta como distinguir tipos de archivo (otra cosa es que el contenido de un archivo tipo texto contenga un texto tipo link).

Comment: @A.Cedano Yo tampoco lo entiendo mucho la verdad. Lo que quiero es reconocer qué archivo es una imagen y qué archivo es un .txt

Comment: @Jakala Exacto, a eso me refiero

Comment: @Jakala quiero decir que **con una imagen se puede construir un link**, sea usando `src`, sea usando un link `http`, `ftp`... que apunte a la imagen. Lo mismo que se puede hacer con un archivo. Yo tampoco entiendo esto que dices: *otra cosa es que el contenido de un archivo tipo texto contenga un texto tipo link*. En fin... aquí el problema es que no hay demasiada claridad en el planteamiento de la pregunta. A mi me gusta ver **ejemplos concretos**, de cómo salen los datos con los que hay que trabajar, de lo contrario es difícil entender la situación.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu caso creo que lo mejor seria buscar el mimetype de cada uno de los archivos que vas analizando. Si tienen en su texto image/jpg, o image/gif... (en general, si tiene la palabra image) entonces es un archivo imagen.

El mimetype lo puedes mirar asi:

```
$finfo = finfo_open(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE); // buscaremos mimetype
$mimetype = finfo_file($finfo, $filename);
finfo_close($finfo);
```

**finfo_open** te permite indicar la informacion que vas a buscar del archivo. A **finfo_file** le indicas el $finfo y la ruta del archivo que quieres analizar.

Comment: Eso es lo que estaba buscando! Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¡Excelente! diste en el clavo.