# Determinar el tipo archivo subido en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando con la subida y lectura de un archivo tipo hoja de calculo y quiero comprobar que su tipo sea correcto, según la documentación de php la clave `type` de la variable global `$_FILES`

```
 $_FILES['fichero_usuario']['type']
```

> El tipo MIME del fichero, si el navegador proporcionó esta
>   información. Un ejemplo sería "image/gif". Este tipo MIME, sin
>   embargo, no se comprueba en el lado de PHP y por lo tanto no se
>   garantiza su valor.

Lo que significa que el navegador no nos asegura el mime correcto y no es bueno confiar en el. La cuestión es como obtener el tipo de mime type correcto porque he visto varias funciones del php para hacerlo como `mime_content_type` y pasa que estás funciones reciben la ruta del archivo real (la cual no tengo, debido a que solo leo el archivo pero no lo subo al servidor), solo tengo la ruta del archivo `temp` que me devuelve `$_fILES`. Alguien sabe como lograr esto ? quedo atengo a cualquier duda.

Comment: que tipo de extension quieres validar? es decir quieres validar si es jpg o pdf o xml etc

Comment: Quiero validar si es un  `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

saludos te dejo un sencillo pero util codigo para validar las extensiones que desees:

```
$formatos_permitidos =  array('doc','docx' ,'xls');
$archivo = $_FILES['doc_file']['name'];
$extension = pathinfo($archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($extension, $formatos_permitidos) ) {
    echo 'Error formato no permitido !!';
}
```

**PATHINFO.-** Devuelve información acerca de un fichero(DOCUMENTO/ARCHIVO,ETC...)
este pathinfo tiene como parametro:

> PATHINFO_DIRNAME, PATHINFO_BASENAME, PATHINFO_EXTENSION y
>   PATHINFO_FILENAME.

Utilizamos el **extension** para obtener la extension de nustro documento..
y mediente esto validamos en un if..

[Documentacion Oficial...mas info](http://php.net/manual/es/function.pathinfo.php)

Espero te sirva y te pueda guia..!!

Comment: excelente gracias por la ayuda

Comment: La comprobacion de la extension no asegura que el archivo sea el deseado. Podrias cambiarle la extension y no pasaria la condicion de formato. De hecho todavia hay gente que se cree que con cambiar la extension de .doc a .html lo convierten en un archivo de web...

Answer (score 1):

Bueno lo que yo hago en tu caso seria obtener el nombre del archivo que estoy subiendo con:

```
$_FILES["fichero_usuario"]["name"]
```

Con esto nos mostraría algo como:

```
Array(
      [0] => archivo1.jpg
      [1] => archivo2.xls
     )
```

Luego hago un **explode()** del nombre para obtener la extensión del archivo así:

```
$archivo = $_FILES["fichero_usuario"]["name"][0]; //archivo1.jpg
$arrayString = explode(".", $archivo); //array(archivo1, jpg)
$extension = end($arrayString); //jpg
```

Como veras hago un **explode** con el carácter **(.)** el cual por lo general seguidamente sigue el la extensión del archivo, eso generaría un **array** el cual lo almaceno en **$arrayString** para luego aplicarle un **end()** y así obtener el ultimo elemento del **array** que contendrá la extensión. Por que un **end()**? porque quizas el nombre del archivo posee puntos entonces nos cercioramos de obtener la extensión con el **end()**. Luego con eso haces una validación como tu quieras o muy mundana como:

```
if($extension != "xls"){
  echo "No es valido";
}else{
  echo "Valido";
}
```

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: en su dia conteste algo parecido. Seria cuestion de ver el mimetype del archivo que has subido. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/166573/saber-si-es-una-imagen-o-link-php/166585#166585